# the value 0 is not of type STRING lisp error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i am a newbie to lisp and i am a making a code to multiply two numbers by shifting and adding using sbcl.here is my code

```
    (
    defun calculator(num1 num2)
    (write-line "In the function")
    (setq res 0)
    (loop for lpr from 0 to 63
        do(progn
                (let ((end-bit (logand num2 1)))
                (if (= end-bit 1)
                    (+ res num1)
                )
                (ash num2 -1)
                (ash num1 1)
            ))
    )
    (write-line res)
)

(write-line "Enter first number : ")
(setq num1 (read))
(write-line "Enter second number : ")
(setq num2 (read))

;;(print num1)
;;(print num2)

(
    if(or (= num1 0) (= num2 0))
    (write-line "result is 0.0")
    (calculator num1 num2)
)
```

but i am getting this error and have no idea how to remove it.Why this is happening , please explain.

```
In the function

debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002A8AF13}>:
  The value 0 is not of type STRING.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(WRITE-LINE 0 1) [tl,external]
0]
```

Comment: write-line expects a string to write out and you pass it a numerical type. You need to convert the numerical type to a string before attempting to print it.

Comment: I think Timo is right, try something like this (write-line (string res))

Comment: @csrcordeiro [**string**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_string.htm) function won't get a string from a number.  Trial and error isn't a great programming method, in general.  Using something like **princ-to-string** or **format** would be better options here.

Comment: You don't need to use **progn** with a do clause in a **loop**.  **loop**'s **do** clause already accepts multiple forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please indent and space your code in the usual way.

```
(defun calculator (num1 num2)
  (write-line "In the function")
  (setq res 0)
  (loop for lpr from 0 to 63
        do (progn
             (let ((end-bit (logand num2 1)))
               (if (= end-bit 1)
                   (+ res num1))
               (ash num2 -1)
               (ash num1 1))))
  (write-line res))

(write-line "Enter first number : ")
(setq num1 (read))
(write-line "Enter second number : ")
(setq num2 (read))

(if (or (= num1 0) (= num2 0))
    (write-line "result is 0.0")
    (calculator num1 num2))
```

Don't `setq` undeclared variables.  Use `let` to create local bindings instead.

```
(defun calculator (num1 num2)
  (write-line "In the function")
  (let ((res 0))
    (loop for lpr from 0 to 63
          do (progn
               (let ((end-bit (logand num2 1)))
                 (if (= end-bit 1)
                     (+ res num1))
                 (ash num2 -1)
                 (ash num1 1))))
    (write-line res)))

(let ((num1 (progn
              (write-line "Enter first number : ")
              (read)))
      (num2 (progn
              (write-line "Enter second number : ")
              (read))))
  (if (or (= num1 0) (= num2 0))
      (write-line "result is 0.0")
      (calculator num1 num2)))
```

You don't need `progn` after the `:do` in a `loop`.

```
(defun calculator (num1 num2)
  (write-line "In the function")
  (let ((res 0))
    (loop for lpr from 0 to 63
          do (let ((end-bit (logand num2 1)))
               (if (= end-bit 1)
                   (+ res num1))
               (ash num2 -1)
               (ash num1 1)))
    (write-line res)))

(let ((num1 (progn
              (write-line "Enter first number : ")
              (read)))
      (num2 (progn
              (write-line "Enter second number : ")
              (read))))
  (if (or (= num1 0) (= num2 0))
      (write-line "result is 0.0")
      (calculator num1 num2)))
```

Your mistake: the error explicitly tells you that "the value 0 is not of type string".  It also tells you that it encountered this error when trying to invoke `write-line`.  Look up the documentation of `write-line`: it takes a `string` as first parameter.  You tried to give it a `0` instead somewhere.  The only place where that could be is at `(write-line res)`, where you always have a number, not a string.

You could use `(format t "result is ~a.~%" res)` instead.

```
(defun calculator (num1 num2)
  (write-line "In the function")
  (let ((res 0))
    (loop for lpr from 0 to 63
          do (let ((end-bit (logand num2 1)))
               (if (= end-bit 1)
                   (+ res num1))
               (ash num2 -1)
               (ash num1 1)))
    (format t "result is ~a.~%" res)))

(let ((num1 (progn
              (write-line "Enter first number : ")
              (read)))
      (num2 (progn
              (write-line "Enter second number : ")
              (read))))
  (if (or (= num1 0) (= num2 0))
      (write-line "result is 0.0")
      (calculator num1 num2)))
```

You need to flush the output to show the question before waiting for the answer.

```
(defun calculator (num1 num2)
  (write-line "In the function")
  (let ((res 0))
    (loop for lpr from 0 to 63
          do (let ((end-bit (logand num2 1)))
               (if (= end-bit 1)
                   (+ res num1))
               (ash num2 -1)
               (ash num1 1)))
    (format t "result is ~a.~%" res)))

(let ((num1 (progn
              (write-line "Enter first number: ")
              (finish-output)
              (read)))
      (num2 (progn
              (write-line "Enter second number: ")
              (finish-output)
              (read))))
  (if (or (= num1 0) (= num2 0))
      (write-line "result is 0.0")
      (calculator num1 num2)))
```

Comment: **(if (= end-bit 1) (+ res num1))** still doesn't *do* anything, though.

Comment: please, can you explain why res is always zero ??

Comment: @amitsingh: because you never change it.  `+` returns the sum of numbers, it doesn't change them.  You might want to use `incf`.  You also might want to use `when` instead of `if` here.